# Rather than use a button to activate a script, have script automatically load when inputs are entered

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am playing around with angular and have made a small little calculator web-app, I have the following `app.component.html`

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>Calculator</h1>  
  <input type="text"  id="firstNumber"  placeholder="First Number" #first>
  <input type="text"  id="secondNumber"  placeholder="Second Number" #second>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" (click) = 'calculate(first.value, second.value)'>Calculate</button>

  <h4>Result: {{result}}</h4>
</div>
```

and my `app.component.ts` looks like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Calculator App in Angular TypeScript';

   result: number;
  calculate(first:number, second:number) {
   this.result = +first + +second;
  }
}
```

This works fine and when I hit the calculate button the two numbers inputted by the user are added together, however, is there a way I can skip the whole button thing and just have the sum load once the two numbers the user wants to add are inputted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the example that you were trying to implement in an earlier question that you then deleted.

You had created a calculator component. Now if you want to display the results in there, you'd have to pass in the numbers as an `Input` property. So that would look something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "calculator",
  templateUrl: "./calculator.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./calculator.component.css"]
})
export class CalculatorComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() firstNumber: number;
  @Input() secondNumber: number;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

And then you can basically print the result in the template once both the numbers are available:

```
<p *ngIf="firstNumber && secondNumber; else elseBlock">
{{ firstNumber + secondNumber }}
</p>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
  Please provide both inputs
</ng-template>
```

Now, to pass the data from `AppComponent`'s template to `CalculatorComponent` you'd use the property binding syntax like this:

```
<div id="first_number">
    <h3>First Number</h3>
    <input [(ngModel)]="firstNumber" type="number">
</div>

<div id="second_number">
  <h3> Second Number</h3>
  <input [(ngModel)]="secondNumber" type="number">
</div>

<div id="solution">
  <h3> Solution: </h3>
  <calculator 
    [firstNumber]="firstNumber"
    [secondNumber]="secondNumber">
  </calculator>
</div>
```

And the `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` would be properties that you would have in the Component class:

```
firstNumber: number = null;
secondNumber: number = null;
```

---

### UPDATE:

You could also have the template for the calculator Component right in the template of the `AppComponent`. That way you won't really have to stress upon the `@Input` properties:

```
<div id="first_number">
    <h3>First Number</h3>
    <input [(ngModel)]="firstNumber" type="number">
</div>

<div id="second_number">
  <h3> Second Number</h3>
  <input [(ngModel)]="secondNumber" type="number">
</div>

<div>
  <h3>Without Calculator</h3>
  <p *ngIf="firstNumber && secondNumber; else elseBlock">
  {{ firstNumber + secondNumber }}
  </p>
  <ng-template #elseBlock>
    Please provide both inputs
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Code Sample**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-calculator-add?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Yes it was but there were serious fundamental flaws in my first attempt at it so I went back did some reading and tried it again

Comment: @Banani720, yeah. I noticed that. This answer would just give you a better mental model of how things are supposed to work in the Angular world. This answer has both the approaches that you could follow. The updated approach would work just fine for your use case. :) Hope the answer helps.

Comment: Hey @SiddAjmera, first off apologies for the late response I've been looking deeply into your answer to help me understand further the nuances of what's going on. While the answer works great for if the form is assigned to the type `number` when I try to set it to text, the "calculator" seems to concatenate the numbers as strings, is there some sort of filter I can use to change the value of a text entry from a string to an integer?

Comment: I specifically mentioned the types of those inputs as `number` to avoid this issue in the first place. But you could do this:  `{{ +firstNumber + +secondNumber }}` I've just added a `+` sign before the `firstNumber` and `lastNumber` properties to convert them into numbers. That way it won't concatenate the inputs as strings. In a more practical use case, you'd have a check on the input itself that errors out if the user inputs a string instead of a number.

Comment: Thanks appreciate it, the main reason I wanted to do it as text is because if the one of the `number` fields was left to zero, it would still show the error prompting the user to use both inputs but having the form as a text field seems to have taken care of this as I assumed.